# Upload (and rename) several photos to the server

Tags: php, mysql

Even if I am not good in development, I am trying to create a form which allows to upload several photos to the server and text to the database.

For the text, no problem. To upload ONE photo too, that's doing it well.

**What I can't do is upload SEVERAL photos in a single form submission.**
Should I use a *while* or *for* or *foreach* loop? If so, how do I retrieve the photos informations?
I specify that I'm not trying to use the "Multiple" function. Even if the files are uploaded in the same form, the user must use separate "File upload" fields.

**I specify that I want to rename the files during the upload.**
With the code below, the upload works but only the renaming of the first file works. The second (and surely the following ones too) are badly renamed. Example for the second:

78_One Plus_Nouveau test_FaceProduct_**pic03.jpgpic04.jpg**

I would to have some help to create a loop for upload images process and rename correctly the image files please ?

```
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Then retrieve all the other information from the form: 
$productname = isset($_POST['productname']) ? $_POST['productname'] : NULL;
$productbrand = isset($_POST['productbrand']) ? $_POST['productbrand'] : NULL;
$addername = isset($_POST['addername']) ? $_POST['addername'] : NULL;
$adderemail = isset($_POST['adderemail']) ? $_POST['adderemail'] : NULL;

// paramètres de connexion
$cbnserver = "xxxxxx";
$cbnuser = "xxxxxxxxx";
$cbnpass = "xxxxxxxxx";
$cbndbname = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";

// Requête d'insertion dans la base
$dbco = new PDO("mysql:host=$cbnserver;dbname=$cbndbname", $cbnuser, $cbnpass);
$dbco->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$req = $dbco->prepare('INSERT INTO `cbnadd_newproduct` (productname, productbrand, addername, adder_email) VALUES(:productname,:productbrand,:addername,:adder_email)');
$req->execute(array(
 'productname' => $productname,
 'productbrand' => $productbrand,
 'addername' => $addername,
 'adder_email' => $adderemail
 ));
$lineid = $dbco->lastInsertId() ;


// Designate the directory where the images will be saved with this code:
$targetFA = "images/". $lineid ."_". $productbrand ."_". $productname ."_FaceProduct_";
$targetFA = $targetFA . basename( $_FILES['photoFA']['name']); 
$targetNV = "images/". $lineid ."_". $productbrand ."_". $productname ."_FaceProduct_";
$targetNV = $targetFA . basename( $_FILES['photoNV']['name']); 


// This writes the photo to the server 
$namefileFA = basename( $_FILES['photoFA']['name']);
$namefileFA = $lineid ."_". $productbrand ."_". $productname ."_". $namefileFA;
$namefileNV = basename( $_FILES['photoFA']['name']);
$namefileNV = $lineid ."_". $productbrand ."_". $productname ."_". $namefileNV;

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photoFA']['tmp_name'],$targetFA) & move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photoNV']['tmp_name'],$targetNV)) { 

 // This code tells you if it is all ok or not.
 echo "<br><br>The file ". $namefileFA. " and has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory<br>"; 
 echo "<br><br>The file ". $namefileNV. " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory<br>"; 

} else {
 echo "<br><br>Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
}
```

Here the HTML code for the photo fields :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="../add.php" method="POST"> 

<!--Product Name: --><input type="text" name="productname"><br>
<h3>Brand</h3>
<!--Brand: --><input type="text" name = "productbrand"><br>

Importer les photos du produit: 
<label for="fileFA" class="label-file" style="cursor:pointer; color:#00b1ca; font-weight:bold;">Couverture/face du produit</label>
<input id="fileFA" class="input-file" type="file" name="photoFA" style="display: none;">
<!--<input type="file" name="photo"><br>-->
<label for="fileNV" class="label-file" style="cursor:pointer; color:#00b1ca; font-weight:bold;">Tableau nutritionnel du produit</label>
<input id="fileNV" class="input-file" type="file" name="photoNV" style="display: none;">
Your name: <input type="text" name = "addername"><br> 
Adder email: <input type="text" name = "adderemail"><br>                                    
<input type="submit" value="Add" class="centered">      
</form>
```

Comment: can you add the form so that we might see the structure and think how it might work?

Comment: what rules do you apply to the renaming of files? Do the new names draw content from any of the text input fields or are they for separate content?

Comment: Why do you not store ( in the db ) reference to the uploaded and renamed files?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius,
1. i updated the first message inserting the HTML code ^^

2. The rool for rename files is : ID of database insert + Brand + Name + NameOfPhotoField + originalNameOfPhoto.  That, it works (except the originalNameOfPhoto part, see my description (bold) please.

3. What do you mean?

Comment: is that the entire form? 2 file and 2 text input elements?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius, Ok I updated the post with the HTML Form.
I would to use a loop for the treatment of the photos. Could be a lot in near future.

Comment: is `$targetNV = "images/". $lineid ."_". $productbrand ."_". $productname ."_FaceProduct_";` correct? Should that not be named `NutritionValue` at the end or similar?

Comment: That's correct.
* I would to use a loop for the treatment of the photos. 
Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put this demo together that shows how you might use a different naming convention in the HTML and tie that in with an array when processing the uploads with PHP.
If you look at the form - particularly the `file` inputs you will note a common name `productimage` but written in array syntax like `productimage[ KEY ]` - that allows access to `KEY` in the PHP whilst in the loop as you will see in the processing portion below. This was written for `mysqli` but will be straightforward to migrate to PDO.

There are plenty of comments throughout to help guide you - but you can test just by editing the db connection details and the `$dir` variable.

```
<?php
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        
        class PostException extends Exception {
            public function __construct( $msg=null, $code=null ){
                parent::__construct( $msg, $code );
            }
            public function geterror(){
                return $this->getMessage();
            }
        }   

        try{
        
            #look at the form - see how it is using this for image name
            $field='productimage';

            if( isset(
                $_FILES[ $field ],
                $_POST['productname'],
                $_POST['productbrand'],
                $_POST['addername'],
                $_POST['adder_email']
            ) ){
                $errors=array();
                $uploads=array();
                $files=array();
                $lineid=false;
                $dbstatus=false;
                
                
                #################################
                # edit this as appropriate...
                $dir=__DIR__ . '/images/uploads';

                
                
                # the names of the various fields in the form - not images
                $args=array(
                    'productname',
                    'productbrand',
                    'addername',
                    'adder_email'
                );
                /*
                    loop through the `$args` array - if a field in the FORM
                    is not set or empty throw & catch a custom exception - 
                    the errors will be displayed later.
                    
                    If no errors, generate the variables based upon the name of
                    the field using variable variables.
                */
                foreach( $args as $fieldname ){
                    try{
                        if( !isset( $_POST[ $fieldname ] ) or empty( $_POST[ $fieldname ] ) ){
                            throw new PostException( sprintf( 'Missing data: The field "%s" is required.', $fieldname ) );
                        } else {
                            ${$fieldname}=$_POST[ $fieldname ];
                        }
                    }catch( PostException $e ){
                        $errors[]=$e->geterror();
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                
                
                
                
                if( empty( $errors ) ){
                    # -------------------------------------------------
                    # ignore the fact that this is a mysqli connection
                    # the same methodology will work with PDO so you 
                    # will need to use your own PDO connection
                    # OR
                    # edit the connection details below to suit
                    # -------------------------------------------------
                    $args=array(
                        'host'  =>  'localhost',
                        'user'  =>  'root',
                        'pwd'   =>  'xxx',
                        'db'    =>  'xxx'
                    );
                    mysqli_report( MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT );
                    $db=new mysqli( ...array_values( $args ) );
                    $db->set_charset('utf8');
                    $db->begin_transaction();
                    
                    
                    
                    /*
                        create table `cbnadd_newproduct` (
                            `id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
                            `productname` varchar(50) null default null,
                            `productbrand` varchar(50) null default null,
                            `addername` varchar(50) null default null,
                            `adder_email` varchar(50) null default null,
                            primary key (`id`)
                        )
                        collate='utf8mb4_general_ci'
                        engine=innodb;

                        +--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
                        | Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
                        +--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
                        | id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
                        | productname  | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
                        | productbrand | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
                        | addername    | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
                        | adder_email  | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
                        +--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
                    */
                    
                    #create the basic sql and prepared statement
                    $sql='insert into `cbnadd_newproduct` 
                            ( `productname`, `productbrand`, `addername`, `adder_email` )
                        values
                            ( ?,?,?,? )';
                    $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
                    
                    
                    /* bind params and execute */
                    $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $productname, $productbrand, $addername, $adder_email );
                    $dbstatus=$stmt->execute();
                    
                    /* get the ID of the last inserted record */
                    $lineid=$db->insert_id;
                    $stmt->close();
                            

                            
                            
                            
                            
                    /*
                        create table `cbnadd_productimages` (
                            `id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
                            `lineid` int(10) unsigned not null,
                            `image` varchar(128) not null,
                            primary key (`id`),
                            index `lineid` (`lineid`)
                        )
                        collate='utf8mb4_general_ci'
                        engine=innodb;
                        
                        +--------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
                        | Field  | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
                        +--------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
                        | id     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
                        | lineid | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
                        | image  | varchar(128)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
                        +--------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
                        
                    */
                    /*
                        It would be usual to record the names / paths of images
                        that you upload so I created a new table for that purpose
                    */
                    # insert records for new images to other table.
                    $sql='insert into `cbnadd_productimages` (`lineid`,`image`) values (?,?)';
                    $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
                    $stmt->bind_param('is', $lineid, $targetname );
                    
                    
                    
                    /*
                        Process the file uploads - using the Array syntax 
                        means you can easily loop through all the files &
                        rename and log to db.
                    */
                    $obj=$_FILES[ $field ];
                    foreach( $obj['name'] as $index => $void ){
                        
                        $name=$obj['name'][ $index ];
                        $tmp=$obj['tmp_name'][ $index ];
                        
                        # ensure we don't process non-existant files
                        if( !empty( $tmp ) ){
                        
                            # new image name format "id_brand_product_category_filename.ext"
                            $targetname=sprintf('%d_%s_%s_%s_%s', $lineid, $productbrand, $productname, $index, $name );
                            
                            # full path for the image to be saved to
                            $targetpath=sprintf('%s/%s', $dir, $targetname );
                            
                            # move the file
                            $status=move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $targetpath );
                            
                            # upload the output variable
                            $uploads[]=$status ? sprintf('The file "%s" has been uploaded OK.<br />Information has been added to the directory: %s', $targetname, ( $dbstatus ? 'True' : 'False' ) ) : sprintf('There was a problem saving "%s".<br />Information logged to db: %s ',$targetname, ( $dbstatus ? 'True' : 'False' ) );
                            
                            # maintain a list of files to be used if db operation fails.
                            $files[]=$targetpath;
                            
                            
                            
                            # save image details... or try to
                            $stmt->execute();
                        }
                    }
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    #commit to database or erase files if there is a problem
                    if( !$db->commit() ) {
                        $errors[]='Failed to commit transaction';
                        foreach( $files as $file ){
                            unlink( $file );
                            $errors[]=sprintf('File deleted: "%s"',$file);
                        }
                        $uploads=[];
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }catch( Exception $e ){
            $errors[]=$e->getMessage();
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <title>PHP: Multiple file uploads - different inputs</title>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <style>
            form{width:60%;float:none;margin:1rem auto;padding:0.5rem 1rem;font-family:monospace;border:1px dashed gray;border-radius:0.5rem;background:whitesmoke;}
            label{width:80%;margin:0.75rem auto;display:block;float:none;padding:0.25rem;}
            label > input{float:right;width:75%;}
            fieldset{margin:1rem auto;padding:1rem;border:1px solid rgba(100,100,100,0.5);background:white;border-radius:0.5rem;}
            form > div{margin:1rem auto}
            [type='submit']{padding:1rem;}
            [type='file']{border:1px solid rgba(100,100,100,0.5); padding:0.25rem;border-radius:0.25rem;color:rgba(100,100,100,0.5);background:rgba(200,200,200,0.5);}
            legend{background:rgba(100,100,100,0.5);color:white;padding:0.5rem;border-radius:0.5rem;min-width:20%;}     
            
            .error{color:red;}
            .success{color:green;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name=uploads' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Product</legend>
                <label>Name:<input type='text' name='productname' /></label>
                <label>Brand:<input type='text' name='productbrand' /></label>
            </fieldset>
            
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Product images</legend>
                <label>Image-Face:<input type='file' name='productimage[FaceProduct]' /></label>
                <label>Image-Nutrition:<input type='file' name='productimage[NutritionValue]' /></label>
                <!-- other images could be added using same method but different index values ~ EG: -->
                <label>Image-Ingredients:<input type='file' name='productimage[Ingredients]' /></label>
                <label>Image-Labels:<input type='file' name='productimage[Labels]' /></label>
            </fieldset>
            
            <fieldset>
                <legend>User details</legend>
                <label>Added by:<input type='text' name='addername' /></label>
                <label>Email:<input type='text' name='adder_email' /></label>
            </fieldset>
            
            <fieldset>
                <input type='submit' />
            </fieldset>
            
            <div>
            <?php
                if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
                    
                    if( !empty( $uploads ) ){
                        foreach( $uploads as $message )printf('<div class="success">%s</div>',$message);
                    }
                    if( !empty( $errors ) ){
                        foreach( $errors as $message )printf('<div class="error">%s</div>',$message);
                    }
                    
                    $errors=$uploads=array();
                }
            ?>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's a very great example Professor !
Thanks, I'll look that today.
But question : what for is the "cbproduct_images" ?

Comment: Not look so important but I got a warning : Warning: mysqli_stmt::execute(): Couldn't fetch mysqli_stmt in... 

About the question : I don't really understand what for is the "cbproduct_images" table ?   
Waiting for your repky, I commented the Insert to 'cbproduct_images' table.  
And, I don't know if there's a connected but I got this message 'There was a problem saving "90_Akai_Nom du produit_Ingredients_...'. 
However, the images are correctly uploaded on the server.

Comment: As I mentioned it is unusual to upload images but not record their names to database - so that new table is for that purpose only... it can easily be removed. If you did not create that table ( and the table creation command was there ) then it will cause errors. Remove that portion of the code

Comment: Hello,
Could you help me with my last answer below please ?

1. There's a problem with the messages, the name of the photo doesn't appear.
2. And even if I insert ONE photo the system update 4 lines on database.

I'm blocked and can't 
Thanks ^^

Comment: Look at the now slightly modified code. There is now `if( !empty( $tmp ) ){}` around a portion of code - this should resolve your issue. Consider accpting the answer perhaps too ?

Comment: That's great Professor. Thank you very much !!  :)

Comment: Oh, didn't realized that was important... Fixed it !
Thank you :)

Comment: no worries - quite funny. Hope you have now got the solution OK ~ this works fine for me so I hope also for you too

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Professor
I create the table, tested the page but two things are strange :

1. There's a problem with the messages, the name of the photo doesn't
   appear.
2. And even if I insert ONE photo the system update 4 lines on database.

Here the messages I got:

> The file "130_Candy_Produit_FaceProduct_pic01.jpg" has been uploaded
> OK. Information has been added to the directory: True
> There was a problem saving "130_Candy_Produit_NutritionValue_". Information logged to db: True
> There was a problem saving "130_Candy_Produit_Ingredients_". Information logged to db: True
> There was a problem saving "130_Candy_Produit_Labels_". Information logged to db: True

And here the code:

```
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    
    class PostException extends Exception {
        public function __construct( $msg=null, $code=null ){
            parent::__construct( $msg, $code );
        }
        public function geterror(){
            return $this->getMessage();
        }
    }
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        try{
        
            #look at the form - see how it is using this for image name
            $field='productimage';

            if( isset(
                $_FILES[ $field ],
                $_POST['productname'],
                $_POST['productbrand'],
                $_POST['addername'],
                $_POST['adder_email']
            ) ){                                        
                $errors=array();
                $uploads=array();
                $files=array();
                $lineid=false;
                $dbstatus=false;                    
                
                #################################
                # edit this as appropriate...
                $dir=__DIR__ . '/imagesStack';

                
                
                # the names of the various fields in the form - not images
                $args=array(
                    'productname',
                    'productbrand',
                    'addername',
                    'adder_email'
                );
                /*
                    loop through the `$args` array - if a field in the FORM
                    is not set or empty throw & catch a custom exception - 
                    the errors will be displayed later.
                    
                    If no errors, generate the variables based upon the name of
                    the field using variable variables.
                */
                foreach( $args as $fieldname ){
                    try{
                        if( !isset( $_POST[ $fieldname ] ) or empty( $_POST[ $fieldname ] ) )throw new PostException( sprintf( 'Missing data: The field "%s" is required.', $fieldname ) );
                        else{
                            ${$fieldname}=$_POST[ $fieldname ];
                        }
                    }catch( PostException $e ){
                        $errors[]=$e->geterror();
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                
                if( empty( $errors ) ){
                    $args=array(
                        'host'  =>  'localhost',
                        'user'  =>  'FFFFF',
                        'pwd'   =>  'EEEEEEEE',
                        'db'    =>  'GGGGGGGGGG'
                    );
                    mysqli_report( MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT );
                    $db=new mysqli( ...array_values( $args ) );
                    $db->set_charset('utf8');
                    $db->begin_transaction();
                    
                    
                    #create the basic sql and prepared statement
                    $sql='insert into `cbnadd_newproduct` 
                            ( `productname`, `productbrand`, `addername`, `adder_email` )
                        values
                            ( ?,?,?,? )';
                    $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
                    
                    
                    /* bind params and execute */
                    $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $productname, $productbrand, $addername, $adder_email );
                    $dbstatus=$stmt->execute();
                    
                    /* get the ID of the last inserted record */
                    $lineid=$db->insert_id;
                    $stmt->close();
                            
                    /*
                        It would be usual to record the names / paths of images
                        that you upload so I created a new table for that purpose
                    */
                    # insert records for new images to other table.
                    $sql='insert into `cbnadd_productimages` (`lineid`,`image`) values (?,?)';
                    $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
                    $stmt->bind_param('is', $lineid, $targetname );                    
                    
                    
                    /*
                        Process the file uploads - using the Array syntax 
                        means you can easily loop through all the files &
                        rename and log to db.
                    */
                    $obj=$_FILES[ $field ];
                    foreach( $obj['name'] as $index => $void ){
                        
                        $name=$obj['name'][ $index ];
                        $tmp=$obj['tmp_name'][ $index ];
                        
                        # new image name format "id_brand_product_category_filename.ext"
                        $targetname=sprintf('%d_%s_%s_%s_%s', $lineid, $productbrand, $productname, $index, $name );
                        
                        # full path for the image to be saved to
                        $targetpath=sprintf('%s/%s', $dir, $targetname );
                        
                        # move the file
                        $status=move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $targetpath );
                        
                        # upload the output variable
                        $uploads[]=$status ? sprintf('The file "%s" has been uploaded OK. Information has been added to the directory: %s', $targetname, ( $dbstatus ? 'True' : 'False' ) ) : sprintf('There was a problem saving "%s". Information logged to db: %s ',$targetname, ( $dbstatus ? 'True' : 'False' ) );
                        
                        # maintain a list of files to be used if db operation fails.
                        $files[]=$targetpath;
                        
                        
                        
                        # save image details... or try to
                        $stmt->execute();
                    }
                    
                    
                    
                    #commit to database or erase files if there is a problem
                    if( !$db->commit() ) {
                        $errors[]='Failed to commit transaction';
                        foreach( $files as $file ){
                            unlink( $file );
                            $errors[]=sprintf('File deleted: "%s"',$file);
                        }
                        $uploads=[];
                    }

                }
            }
        }catch( Exception $e ){
            $errors[]=$e->getMessage();
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <title>PHP: Multiple file uploads - different inputs</title>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <style>
            form{width:60%;float:none;margin:1rem auto;padding:0.5rem 1rem;font-family:monospace;border:1px dashed gray;border-radius:0.5rem;background:whitesmoke;}
            label{width:80%;margin:0.5rem auto;display:block;float:none;padding:0.25rem;}
            label > input{float:right;width:75%;}
            fieldset{margin:1rem auto;padding:1rem;border:1px solid rgba(100,100,100,0.5);background:white;border-radius:0.5rem;}
            form > div{margin:1rem auto}
            [type='submit']{padding:1rem;}
            legend{background:rgba(100,100,100,0.5);color:white;padding:0.5rem;border-radius:0.5rem;min-width:20%;}     
            
            .error{color:red;}
            .success{color:green;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name='uploads' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Product</legend>
                <label>Name:<input type='text' name='productname' /></label>
                <label>Brand:<input type='text' name='productbrand' /></label>
            </fieldset>
            
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Product images</legend>
                <label>Image-Face:<input type='file' name='productimage[FaceProduct]' /></label>
                <label>Image-Nutrition:<input type='file' name='productimage[NutritionValue]' /></label>
                <!-- other images could be added using same method but different index values ~ EG: -->
                <label>Image-Ingredients:<input type='file' name='productimage[Ingredients]' /></label>
                <label>Image-Labels:<input type='file' name='productimage[Labels]' /></label>
            </fieldset>
            
            <fieldset>
                <legend>User details</legend>
                <label>Added by:<input type='text' name='addername' /></label>
                <label>Email:<input type='text' name='adder_email' /></label>
            </fieldset>
            
            <fieldset>
                <input type='submit' />
            </fieldset>
            
            <div>
            <?php
                if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
                    if( !empty( $uploads ) ){
                        foreach( $uploads as $message )printf('<div class="success">%s</div>',$message);
                    }
                    if( !empty( $errors ) ){
                        foreach( $errors as $message )printf('<div class="error">%s</div>',$message);
                    }
                }
            ?>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```